# Bash Shell commands stop creating files when put into a function

Tags: bash, shell, grep

the following code is to find files using grep, and then copy them into a new folder with a new name(found_file1 found_file2 etc.).

It works when search(){...} is removed and the program is run as is. But when put into a function, it deletes-creates the Found folder but fails to create the files into it.

```
#!/bin/bash

search(){


founddir=$(pwd)/Found

#---------gets inputs
echo "Enter the name of the directory:"
read searchdir
echo "Enter the keyword: "
read keyword

#-----this if statement checks if there are matching files
if grep -q -lr $keyword "$(pwd)/$searchdir"
then

    rm -rf Found 
    #removes old Found file, we're running this over and over it becomes more convinient to automate it this way. will be removed later
    mkdir Found 
#creates found file folder

    grep -q -lr $keyword "$(pwd)/$searchdir" | while read -r dir ; do 
        #------creates filepath to use in touch command, UNCERTAIN if it manages to
        file="$founddir/found_$(basename $dir)"
    enter code here
        #should create a file but does not
        touch $file

        #cant cp contents because file is not created
        cp -p $dir $file

    done

    echo "Files were copied to the Found directory!"

else
echo "Keyword not found in files!"
fi

}
search
```

we have tried putting/removing quotes from variable declerations, but it did not seem to help.

Comment: Enough content to understand your problem and test solutions needs to be **included in the question itself, as text**. Content behind a link or in an image doesn't count towards compliance with the [mre] rules in the Help Center.

Comment: See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: To help _you_ understand the problem yourself, so you can ask a better question about it, I'd suggest comparing the logs of `bash -x yourscript` both with and without the function / outer-context change. And you definitely _do_ need more quotes for your code to be correct/robust -- run it through https://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds; that might not solve the specific problem that brought you here, but it solves other problems, and we require a question to be about _only one specific problem_.

Comment: (the big reason for asking you to look at `set -x` traces is so you can understand what's happening during execution under the hood, and thereby _ask a more specific problem_, simplifying to factor out code that isn't actually related to the thing that went wrong; obviously, you can't do this until you know at what point in execution actual and expected behavior diverge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your function should do but your i think your problem is in this line:

```
  grep -q -lr $keyword "$(pwd)/$searchdir" | while read -r dir ; do
```

`-q` does not return anything but exit code. so in this case when you are piping output of `grep` to `while` loop, there is nothing for `while` to do.

what you might need to do is to remove `-q` from the grep so it will return files names for `while` to set for `dir` variable in your loop and do the rest.

Comment: This is true, but it also means the question is badly mis-asked: After all, it claims that the same code works when the code isn't in a function, and that can't possibly be true.